# How to connect to an existing socket io connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My application works this way :

1. The user logins to the website
2. JavaScript connect to the Socket.IO server, and transmit PHPSESSID
3. Socket.IO use PHPSESSID to connect to database and then get `user_id`
4. With `user_id` we connect one more time to database to get `user_place`
5. The user is then connected to the room `user_place` and can talk with other people here

The thing is that `user_place` can changes via, for example, another php script.

So when it changes, **I need to tell the current socket io connection to fetch new “user_place” from database**, so it can leave the current room and connect to the new one.

How can I achieve this ?

I had 2 guesses :

1. When the php script is executed, connect to the existing Socket.IO connection and execute code like `client.on('update_place'), function() {}`. **The thing is that I don't know how to connect to an existing connection** (is it possible ?)
2. Has a setTimeout() function checking constatly on the database if “user_place” has changed or not (but perfs will be terrible)

Here is some simplified code of the node server :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {

    var user_place;

    // Read client cookies
    if(client.handshake.headers['cookie']) {
        var cookies = cookie.parse(client.handshake.headers['cookie']);
    }

    // If cookies exist, connect to database and get “user_place”
    if(cookies) {
        connection.query("SELECT session_value, session_time FROM sessions WHERE session_id = ?", [cookies.PHPSESSID], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(rows[0]) {
                var session_value_json = JSON.parse(atob(rows[0].session_value));
                user_id = session_value.user_id;

                if(user_id) {
                    connection.query( "SELECT place FROM users WHERE id = ?", [user_id], function(err, rows, fields) {

                        // Set data user_place
                        user_place = rows[0].user_place;

                        // Join the room
                        client.join(user_place);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Chatting...
    client.on('message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(user_place).emit('message', {     
            user_id         : user_id,
            message_content : data.message
            } 
        );  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can connect to Socket.IO from PHP, but you can go another way.

First, create an object that will store relationship between user IDs and socket IDs:

```
var userSocketIds = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    ...
        connection.query( "SELECT place FROM users WHERE id = ?", [user_id], function(err, rows, fields) {

            // Set data user_place
            user_place = rows[0].user_place;

            // Join the room
            client.join(user_place);

            userSocketIds[user_id] = client.id;
            client.on('disconnect', function() {
                delete userSocketIds[user_id];  //collect garbage
            });
        });
    ...
});
```

Thus, if you know user ID you can get Socket.IO client ID like this:

```
var clientId = userSocketIds[user_id];
```

And then, when `user_place` is changed, send POST request to node (for example, to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/change_user_place`) and pass `user_id` and `new_place` parameters to it.

On the node side you can handle such requests with Express and change a user's room:

```
app.post('/change_user_place', function(req, res) {
    var clientId = userSocketIds[req.body.user_id];
    if (clientId && io.sockets.connected[clientId]) {
        io.sockets.connected[clientId].join(req.body.new_place);  //join user to new_place
    }
});
```

Of course, you can also send `GET` request instead of `POST` (and it would be easier to implement -- you don't need to install `body-parser` middleware), but with actions that change something on the server side it's better you use `POST` method. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get).

You also may (and should) implement something like password authorization. It's easy: your PHP script just has to pass some password along with user ID and new place, and node should verify this password.

Good luck and sorry for my English.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanations ! It's perfect and really helped me.

Just for information, I was planning to use Elephant.io (http://elephant.io/) to connect to NodeJS via PHP. But the way you did it allowed me to send data via http, and it's indeed simplier, faster and easier ! 

Again, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for the link. Since I also have to combine PHP and Node.js in my work it may be useful to me :)